# Outlook Add-In: Ignore On-send Event when Remote Service Unavailable

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I developed an office.js add-in using the ItemSend event. Everything works fine if external service available. But when i was testing send email operation for "unavailable service scenario" get an error like bellow:

"We're sorry, we couldn't access [Add-in Name]. Make sure you have a network connection. If the problem continues, please try again later."
and
"The add-in [Add-in Name] has prevented this item from being sent."

So the question is how to ignore add-in for this situation?

I am testing on web browser.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The group policy **Disable send when web extensions can't load** must be set to `Disable` on each applicable machine if you want to let users send emails if the add-in is not available. Read more about that in the [Install Outlook add-ins that use on-send](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows#install-outlook-add-ins-that-use-on-send) section of MSDN.

Comment: Note that the Group Policy "Disable send when web extensions can't load" does not affect this scenario, and is actually even stricter. If Outlook cannot retrieve manifests from the Exchange server, then all send will be disabled. That GPO is also meant for deploying compliance Item Send Add-ins and to ensure all your users have the latest manifests that you have uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at this time. The Item Send Add-ins are currently meant for mission critical and compliance apps, and if your add-in is not available then mail can not be sent. We are aware of the demand for a "softer" Item Send add-in that will allow for send to occur if your add-in is not available, but we do not have anything to announce at this time.

Note that the Group Policy "Disable send when web extensions can't load" does not affect this scenario, and is actually even stricter. If Outlook cannot retrieve manifests from the Exchange server, then all send will be disabled. That GPO is also meant for deploying compliance Item Send Add-ins and to ensure all your users have the latest manifests that you have uploaded.

Comment: Can we add backup or alternate URL for our function file in Manifest?

Comment: Hey, did anything change since you posted this?

Comment: Hi, Any new updates on this please?