# Error: Outlook can't send this message because there's a problem with the add-in

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

We are working on creating of Add-in for the Outlook. And it works correctly for normal cases.
But we faced the problem that if the server with execute code for our add-in is down, then a user can't send email and get error 'Outlook can't send this message because there's a problem with the add-in [Add-in name]'.

We read this topic [Outlook Add-In: Ignore On-send Event when Remote Service Unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64893065/outlook-add-in-ignore-on-send-event-when-remote-service-unavailable) and tried to change policy(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows#install-outlook-add-ins-that-use-on-send), but it doesn't help us.

What should we do to not stop sending email even if our add-in server is down?

manifest file

```
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
           xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0"
           xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>some guid</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Test ProviderName</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>da-DK</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Add-in name"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="Test description"/>

  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-64.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-128.png"/>

  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/help"/>

  <AppDomains>
    <!-- All domains you want to access must be listed here (origin) -->
    <AppDomain>https://localhost:3000/</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://localhost:5001/</AppDomain>

  </AppDomains>

  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
  </Hosts>

  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>

   <!-- Old schema. This will be overridden by the VersionOverrides below. -->
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemEdit">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html"/>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <!-- /Old schema. -->

  <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>

  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit" />
  </Rule>

  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <!-- On Send requires VersionOverridesV1_1 -->
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
      <Description resid="residAppDescription" />
      <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
          <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
        </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>

      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
          <!-- Event-based activation happens in a lightweight runtime.-->
          <Runtimes>
            <!-- HTML file including reference to or inline JavaScript event handlers.
                 This is used by Outlook on the web and Outlook on the new Mac UI. -->
            <Runtime resid="WebViewRuntime.Url">
              <!-- JavaScript file containing event handlers. This is used by Outlook on Windows. -->
              <Override type="javascript" resid="JSRuntime.Url"/>
            </Runtime>
          </Runtimes>

          <DesktopFormFactor>
            <FunctionFile resid="WebViewRuntime.Url" />
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events">
              <!-- Using ItemSend allows us to open dialogs from the send event, as opposed to when using the
                  "Smart-Alert" on send handler.
                  The draw-back of this is that we cannot publish this add-in to Microsoft's AppSource.

                  The function must be on the global scope.
               -->
              <Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="onMessageSendHandler" />
            </ExtensionPoint>

            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="LaunchEvent">
              <LaunchEvents>
                <LaunchEvent Type="OnMessageCompose" FunctionName="onMessageComposeHandler"/>
                <LaunchEvent Type="OnMessageAttachmentsChanged" FunctionName="onMessageAttachmentsChangedHandler"/>
              </LaunchEvents>
              <SourceLocation resid="WebViewRuntime.Url"/>
            </ExtensionPoint>

          </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>
      <Resources>
        <bt:Urls>
          <!-- The JavaScript code is hosted on a secure and trusted web server. -->
          <bt:Url id="WebViewRuntime.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html"/>
          <bt:Url id="JSRuntime.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.js" />
        </bt:Urls>
      </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>

</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: What is the target platform where you got a problem with sending emails - web browser, Windows or MacOS desktop app?

Comment: Windows and Web browser

Comment: The article mentioned in your post covers these platforms. There are no other settings unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***An on-send add-in will run if its backend is online and reachable. If the backend is offline, send is disabled.***

By default, the on-send policy is disabled which means the currently downloaded manifests of the on-send add-ins (not necessarily the latest versions) run on message or meeting items being sent. Administrators can enable the `on-send policy` by ensuring the user's group policy setting `Block send when web add-ins can't load` is set to `Enabled`. To disable the policy for a user, the administrator should set it to `Disabled`. To manage this policy setting, you can do the following:

1. Download the latest [Administrative Templates tool](https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=49030).
2. Open the `Local Group Policy Editor` (`gpedit.msc`).
3. Navigate to `User Configuration` > `Administrative Templates` > `Microsoft Outlook 2016` > `Security` > `Trust Center`.
4. Select the `Block send when web add-ins can't load` setting.
5. Open the link to edit policy setting.
6. In the `Block send when web add-ins can't load` dialog window, select `Enabled` or `Disabled` as appropriate then select `OK` or `Apply` to put the update into effect.

In older versions of the `Administrative Templates` tool, the policy name was `Disable send when web extensions can't load`. Substitute in this name in later steps if needed.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! I tried this solution today. it works if the add-in run before and has been cached.
but if a user installs the add-in and the server with add-in is not reachable, then it doesn't work and sending email would be failed(user can't send email from his outlook client till he remove the add-in)

Comment: The best what you could do is to post to https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues . There is really nothing you can do out of that.